# Creating Multiple Dataframes based on starting characters in one column and matching to Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, group-by

Let’s say I have a dictionary

```
area_codes = {
“New Hampshire”:[‘602’]
“Vermont”:[‘803’]
}
```

And a data frame that looks like

| name | job title | phone number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | doctor | 602-123-4567 |
| Joe | pharmacist | 803-123-4567 |

And I want to split this into two dataframes based on the first three
Characters of each row in “phone number”

And then

Save the dataframes as

“state(key) contact list.csv”

By matching the area code in df[phone number] to the value in the dictionary.

I have tried .groupby() but haven’t had any luck.

I also tried a for loop to crate dataframes and save them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a function that separates each of the area codes. Then just separate each of the data in your main dataframe and, at the end, save them with the name of each of the areas.

```
import pandas as pd

area_codes = {
    "New Hampshire": ['602'],
    "Vermont": ['803']
}

data = {
    'name': ['Bob', 'Joe'],
    'job title': ['doctor', 'pharmacist'],
    'phone number': ['602-123-4567', '803-123-4567']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Function to get the state based on the area code
def get_state(area_code):
    return next((state for state, codes in area_codes.items() if area_code in codes), None)

# Extract the state based on the first three characters of the phone number
df['state'] = df['phone number'].str[:3].apply(get_state)

# Create a dictionary of DataFrames based on the state
state_dataframes = {state: group_df.drop(columns=['state']) for state, group_df in df.groupby('state')}

# Save each DataFrame to a CSV file
for state, state_df in state_dataframes.items():
    filename = f"{state} contact list.csv"
    state_df.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

Output:

```
One csv file for each code area
```